# How to block execution of spring aspect written around method which has async rxjava tasks running inside till completion of rxjava observable tasks?

Tags: java, spring, observable, rx-java, spring-aop

I have written a @Around aspect over a method which has different async rxjava tasks executing. The method returns the controls immediately after spawning the rxjava observable tasks and aspect starts executing resulting in NullPointerExecution

In an aspect, I am writing one more rxjava observable task which I tried to wait untill all other tasks are completed

```
@Around
public void method (){
    // Spawns the few rxjava observable tasks in async way which fill some request level object with output data
    // control returns immediately and aspect execution proceeds without waiting for output data to fill by async tasks
}
```

Need aspect code to wait untill all internal async rxjava observable tasks finish their execution

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I have no idea what you are talking about. Do everyone here and yourself a favour, give us something to compile, run and analyse. Just in case you wondered why there are no answers...

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex for your reply. Unfortunately, I can not provide the MCVE ! 
To explain more, in short I am looking for a way where an observable task can be blocked until some action(lets some variable is set to true) is completed.

Comment: Why can't you? That's just a lame excuse. Others should work for you but you don't want to do your part of the job? I don't want copyright-protected original code. An MCVE is a minimal + complete example reproducing the problem. Boiling your problem down into the smallest project reproducing your problem would even help you understand the root cause better. Many SO users told me in the past that while they were trying to create the MCVE, they already found the solution by themselves.

Comment: Sure, will try to create MCVE. Thank you!

Comment: Fine. If it is too much code to fit into your updated question, feel free to share a GitHub link.